# Artifactory - delete artifacts older than 20 days

Tags: groovy, repository, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with `Artifactory`. I have a groovy script for defining Jenkins pipeline Job. On the `Artifactory`, i have a repository for my project with many sub-folders. For every Jenkins new build, a new folder is created into `Artifactory` repo. The idea is that i don't know how to delete the folders and content artifacts which are older than 20 days. I used `AQL` to retrieve them, but i don't know how to delete what i retrieved. I can not use `Artifactory Cleanup Plugin` because i don't have access to install it on the platform.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before publishing the build-info, define 20 days build retention:

```
// Delete build after 20 days
buildInfo.retention maxDays: 20, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
```

For more information:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-TriggeringBuildRetention

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I have free version and this feature can´t be used. However I can delete artifacts. How can you remove artifact FOLDERS older than certain time (for ex 3 months)